# RoR/Squeel - How do I use Squeel::Nodes::Join/Predicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, squeel

I just recently inherited a project where the previous developer used Squeel.

I've been studying Squeel for the past day now and know a bit about how to use it from what I could find online. The basic use of it is simple enough.

What I haven't been able to find online (except for on ruby-doc.org, which didn't give me much), is how to use `Squeel::Nodes::Join` and `Squeel::Nodes::Predicate`.
The only thing I've been able to find out is that they are nodes representing join associations / predicate expressions, which I had figured as much. What I still don't know is how to use them.

Can someone help me out or point me toward a good tutorial/guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might as well answer this since I was able to figure out quite a bit through trial and error and by using [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/s/squeel-1.2.1/Squeel/Nodes/Node.html) as a guide. Everything I say here is not a final definition to each of these. It's just what I know that may be able to help someone out in the future in case anyone else is stuck making dynamic queries with Squeel.

## Squeel::Nodes::Stub

Let's actually start with Squeel::Nodes::Stub. This is a Squeel object that can take either a symbol or a string and can convert it into the name of a table or column. So you can create a new `Squeel::Nodes::Stube.new("value")` or `Squeel::Nodes::Stube.new(:value)` and use this stub in other Squeel nodes. You'll see examples of it being used below.

## Squeel::Nodes::Join

Squeel::Nodes::Join acts just like you might suspect. It is essentially a variable you can pass in to a Squeel joins{} that will then perform the join you want. You give it a stub (with a table name), and you can also give it another variable to change the type of join (I only know how to change it to outer join at the moment). You create one like so:

`Squeel::Nodes::Join.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new(:custom_fields), Arel::OuterJoin)`

The stub is used to let the Join know we want to join the custom_fields table, and the Arel::OuterJoin is just to let the Join know we want to do an outer join. Again, you don't have to put a second parameter into Squeel::Nodes::Join.new(), and I think it will default to performing an inner join. You can then join this to a model:

`Person.joins{Squeel::Nodes::Join.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new(:custom_fields), Arel::OuterJoin)}`

## Squeel::Nodes::Predicate

Squeel::Nodes::Predicate may seem pretty obvious at this point. It's just a comparison. You give it a stub (with a column name), a method of comparison (you can find them all in the Predicates section on [Squeel's github](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel)) and a value to compare with, like so:

`Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub(:value), :eq, 5)`

You can even AND or OR two of them together pretty easily.

**AND**: `Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub(:value1), :eq, 5) & Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub(:value2), :eq, 10)`

**OR**: `Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub(:value1), :eq, 5) | Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub(:value2), :eq, 10)`

These will return either a **Squeel::Nodes::And** or a **Squeel::Nodes::Or** with the nested Squeel::Nodes::Predicates.

Then you can put it all together like this (of course you'd probably have the joins in a variable, a, and the predicates in a variable b, because you are doing this dynamically, otherwise you should probably be using regular Squeel instead of Squeel nodes):

`Person.joins{Squeel::Nodes::Join.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new(:custom_fields), 
Arel::OuterJoin)}.where{Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub(:value1), :eq, 5) | Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub(:value2), :eq, 10)}`

I unfortunately could not figure out how to do subqueries though :(

Comment: link for ruby-doc is broken.